# Interop Best Practices: Should I use Static Class, or Normal Classes

Tags: c#, c++

I have a front end C# that needs to call a C++ back end. So interop is needed.

I have an "interop layer", that converts the C# data structure into C++ structure, and do all the memory freeing grunt work.

My question is, should I write this interop layer as a *static* class, or should I wrap it in a normal class and instantiate it as an object when I need to use it?

Comment: @Graviton: This is off-topic for this site.  This site is for doing code reviews, which means questions should have code to be looked at.

Comment: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/ may be a better site for this question.

Comment: @Mark, I think this question belongs here-- it's all about how the code should *be* and best practices, so it's a form of code review service that I'm asking about.

Comment: @Graviton: Then that's what Programmers.SE is for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`static` (especially static classes) should be avoided as much as possible, IMO. It results in inflexible and hard to test code. A proper normal class would also allow you to do some initialization or cleanup (via `IDisposable`) if needed, and you could easily switch to an interface to utilize mocking or replace the backend with a managed one.

Answer (score 2):

I would definitely go with a non-static class. This allows you to implement [IDisposable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.aspx) and clean up your un-managed resources in the way .NET prefers.

Answer (score 1):

If you are doing TDD, you might want to read this article from the [Google Testing blog](http://googletesting.blogspot.com/2008/12/static-methods-are-death-to-testability.html).

I really liked the following quote from the article, which summarizes the problem really well:

> The basic issue with static methods is they are procedural code. I have no idea how to unit-test procedural code. Unit-testing assumes that I can instantiate a piece of my application in isolation. During the instantiation I wire the dependencies with mocks/friendlies which replace the real dependencies. With procedural programing there is nothing to "wire" since there are no objects, the code and data are separate.